# How to add select state dropdown field in custom phtml form and save in database(frontend) in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, module, database

I have added a select state dropdown field in my custom phtml file. But not able to save that value in database in Magento2.2.5?

> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Amy/Contactform/Block

```
<?php

namespace Amy\Contactform\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class ContactForm extends \Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm
{

    public function __construct(
            Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Directory\Block\Data $directoryBlock, 
            array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        $this->directoryBlock = $directoryBlock;
    }

    public function getCountries()
    {
        $country = $this->directoryBlock->getCountryHtmlSelect();
        return $country;
    }
    public function getRegion()
    {
        $region = $this->directoryBlock->getRegionHtmlSelect();
        return $region;
    }
}
```

> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Amy/Contactform/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" type="Amy\Contactform\Block\ContactForm" />
</config>
```

> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Amy/Contactform/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Amy_Contactform" setup_version="2.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Amy/Contactform/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Amy_Contactform',
    __DIR__
);
```

> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Amy/Contactform/view/frontend/layout/contact_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
        <referenceBlock name="contactForm">
        <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Amy_Contactform::form.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Amy/Contactform/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<?php

$regionList = $block->getRegion();
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
/** @var \Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm $block */
?>
<form class="form contact"
      action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Contact Us')) ?></span></legend><br />


        <div class="field name required">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('FirstName')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="name" id="name" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Name')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('name') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field lastname required">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('LastName')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="lastname" id="last_name" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('LastName')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('lastname') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('email') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field telephone required">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Telephone')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone Number')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('telephone') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-- <div class="field telephone">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Telephone')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone Number')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('telephone')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div> -->

        <div class="field address1 required">
            <label class="label" for="address1"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address1')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="address1" id="address1" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Address1')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('address1')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field address2 required">
            <label class="label" for="address2"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address2')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="address2" id="address2" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Address2')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('address2')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field city required">
            <label class="label" for="city"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('City')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="city" id="city" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('city')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="field stateprovince required">
            <label class="label" for="stateprovince"><span><?php  echo __('State/Province') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <?php echo $regionList?> 

            </div>
        </div>


         <div class="field zipcode required">
            <label class="label" for="zipcode"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Zipcode')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="zipcode" id="zipcode" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Zipcode')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('zipcode')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="field comment">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Message')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('What’s on your mind?')) ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3"><?= $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('comment')) ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- <script>
$(document).on('change','#country',function() {
    var param = 'country='+$('#country').val();
    $.ajax({
        showLoader: true,
        url: YOUR_URL_HERE,
        data: param,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        //data.value has the array of regions
    });
});
</script> -->
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please post the code which you have tired

Comment: check my updated question.

Comment: You donot have country field means you want to implement region for a particular country?

Comment: Yes, simply I want to show the region dropdown and save in db.

Comment: you donot get any question,  every country has it own regions ,So  my question os that you want to show all country region on this dropdown?>

Comment: I want to get only US region in state dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a particular country region list at dropdown using `getRegionHtmlSelect` then you have to do some code.

First, you have to remove class injection like `\Magento\Directory\Block\Data $directoryBlock,` from `__construct()`.

and you have to  pass country id to  `\Magento\Directory\Block\Data $directoryBlock`

**Block class code may be look like:**

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Block;

class ContactForm extends \Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm {
    protected $directoryBlock;
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, 
            array $data = array()) 
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    protected function getDirectoryBlock()
    {
        if(null === $this->directoryBlock)
        {
            $this->directoryBlock = $this->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('Magento\Directory\Block\Data','contact.directoy')
                    ->getCountryId('US');
        }
        return $this->directoryBlock;
    }
    /**
     *  Getting Region drop down
     * @return string
     */
    public function  getRegionHtml()
    {
        if($this->getDirectoryBlock())
        {
            return $this->getDirectoryBlock()->getRegionHtmlSelect();
        }
        return '';
    }
    public function  getCountryHtml()
    {
        if($this->getDirectoryBlock())
        {
            return $this->getDirectoryBlock()->getCountryHtmlSelect($defValue = null,
                    $name = 'country_id',
                    $id = 'country',
                    $title = 'Country');
        }      
      return '';   
    } 


}
```

At phtml file, you have to add below code `Magento\Directory\Block\Data` for getting  region drop down

```
<?= $block->getRegionHtml() ?>
```

as per as code of  field name would be `region` and  html id `state`

And country html

```
<?= $block->getCountryHtml() ?>
```